# Cassandra node almost out of space, but nodetool cleanup is increasing disk use?

Tags: cassandra

One of our nodes was at 95% disk use and we added another node to the cluster to hopefully rebalance but the disk space didn't drop on the node. I tried doing nodetool cleanup assuming that excess keys were on the node, but the disk space is increasing! Will cleanup actually reduce the size?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it will, but you have to be careful because a compaction is calculated and it generates temporary files and tmp link files that will increase disk space until the cleaned up compacted table is calculated.

So I would go into your data directory and figure out what your keyspace sizes are using

```
du -h -s *
```

Then individually clean up the smaller keyspaces (you can specify a keyspace in the nodetool cleanup command with nodetool cleanup ) until you have some overhead. To get an idea of how much space is being freed, tail the log and cat/grep for cleaned compactions:

```
tail <system.log location> | grep 'eaned'
```

I'd recommend you don't try to cleanup a keyspace that is more that half the size of your remaining disk space. Hopefully that is possible.

If you don't have enough space you'll have to shut down the node, attach a bigger disk, copy the data files over to the bigger disk, repoint the yaml to the new data directories, then restart up. This is useful for things like SSDs that are expensive and small, but the main spinning disks are cheaper and bigger.

Comment: Yep, by monitoring the keyspace I can see each table in a keyspace's data directory grow and then shrink

I also had some leftover tmplink files which may have been left over from the aborted cleanup before that seemed to get cleaned up with the node restart. But that was independent of the cleanup measurements I made on some of the smaller keyspaces.

So this is the only way to get that excess key data to expunge when a new node is added?

Comment: Oh, and the du command was also useful for watching the table subdirectories grow and shrink, so you could see what table it was working on besides tailing the system log.

df -k seems to trail recovering the overall space on AWS a bit, by like 10 seconds sometimes